# HeaderParser() does not get all headers?

Tags: python, imaplib

Here is my code:

```
import imaplib
from email.parser import HeaderParser
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
conn.login('example@gmail.com', 'password')
conn.select()
conn.search(None, 'ALL')
data = conn.fetch('1', '(BODY[HEADER])')
header_data = data[1][0][1]
newdata = header_data.decode('utf-8')
parser = HeaderParser()
msg = parser.parsestr(newdata)
print (msg.keys())
```

This prints out the keys(headers) : Mime-version, x-no-auto-attachment, received, date, messageID, subject, from. to, content type.

However there is 2 missing, which are X-GM-THRID and X-Gmail-Labels? Any ideas why and how can i solve this?

Comment: I assume you mean X-GM-Labels instead of X-Gmail-Labels?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think those are in the email header but extensions to the `FETCH` command:

```
conn.fetch('1', '(BODY[HEADER] X-GM-THRID X-GM-Labels)')
```

See Gmail's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_the_gmail_thread_id_x-gm-thrid).